# Node.js - Why would a Promise appear to return both fulfilled and rejected?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

**Node.JS:** Version 10.16.0

**Question:** Why would a Promise appear to return both fulfilled and rejected?

**Background:** The following simplified test server is meant to connect to a MongoDB Atlas database. `mongoose.connect()` returns a promise. For some reason the `.then()` and `.catch()` statements are firing and the console prints both 'connected' and 'not connected'. I didn't think that was possible.

```
"use strict";

const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const path = require('path');

require('dotenv').config({ path: path.join(__dirname, 'controllers/.env') });

const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECTION, { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then( console.log('connected') )
    .catch( console.log('not connected') );

app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your actually calling both `console.log()` statements BEFORE the promise resolves or rejects.  This is because you're not putting them inside a function and passing that function to `.then()` and `.catch()`.  Instead, you're calling them immediately and then passing their return value to `.then()` and `.catch()`.  Remember, you always have to pass a function reference to `.then()` and `.catch()` so that the promise infrastructure can call that function sometime LATER.

In fact, your code is analogous to this:

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECTION, { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(undefined)
    .catch(undefined);

// these will both get called before the above promise resolves or rejects
console.log('connected');
console.log('not connected')
```

You call the two `console.log()` statements at the same time as `.then()` and `.catch()` are called.

---

Instead, you need to wrap them inside a callback function that you pass to `.then()` and `.catch()` like this:

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECTION, { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(() => console.log('connected') )
    .catch(() => console.log('not connected') );
```

Or, perhaps this is more demonstrable with regular functions:

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECTION, { useNewUrlParser: true }).then(function() {
    console.log('connected');
}).catch(function() {
    console.log('not connected');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The then & catch should receive a callback function, you are calling console.log.

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECTION, { useNewUrlParser: true })
.then(() => console.log('connected') )
.catch(() => console.log('not connected') );
```